# Changing order of dictionaries keys based on preferred order

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, ordereddictionary

The input is a dictionary, for example:

```
{'first_name':'Jane', 'occupation': 'astronaut', 'age':27, 'last_name':'Doe'}
```

The keys need to be rearranged to be in a specific order, given in a list, for example:

```
preferred_order = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'location']
```

The dictionary might not have all the keys in the `preferred_order` list, and might have keys that don't appear on the list.

In this specific case, the result of the sorting should be:

```
{'first_name':'Jane', 'last_name':'Doe', 'age':27, 'occupation': 'astronaut'}
```

Key `location` didn't get added to the dictionary, and the keys not in `preferred_order`  are at the end.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi OK, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Suggested algorithm:**

1. Create a new, initially empty, dictionary;
2. Iterate through `preferred_order`: for every `key` in `preferred_order`, add `key: value` to the new dictionary if it exists in the old dictionary, and remove it from the old dictionary;
3. for every remaining `key: value` pair in the old dictionary, add it to the new dictionary.

For step 3, you can use `dict.update` or `|=`.

**Further reading:**

- [documentation on `dict.update` and `|=`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update);
- [more about `|=`](https://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584);
- [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/613218/3080723);
- You can search for "sort dictionary by key" on stackoverflow, but be aware that most answers are outdated and recommend using `collections.OrderedDict` instead of `dict`, which is no longer necessary since Python 3.7.